# How to pass app data to a VueRouter component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using VueRouter to load templates depending on the URL. When I try to use a property defined in `app.data` in the components, I receive a `[VueWarn] Property or method "role" is not defined`.

How can I pass every data property to the child components?

This is my script:

```
const Home = { template: '<p>home page, {{role}}</p>' }
const NotFound = { template: '<p>Page not found</p>' }

const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Home}
    {path: '*', component: NotFound}
]

Vue.use(VueRouter)
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        role: 0,
        cookiesAlert: true
    },
    router: new VueRouter({routes})
})
```

Comment: Take a look at [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) if you want to share global data across your application.

Comment: Use vuex like @Psidom said. The child components don't share the same as the parent components.

Comment: You have to use `Vuex` for this case like what the above 2 comments have suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your router construction options are not set properly. Usually, I prefer to use 'named routes', therefore what I will set is:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   routes: [
        { name: 'role', path: '/:role', component: User },
        { path: '*', component: Home }
   ]
})
```

And if I don't understand your question wrong, what you want to do is pass the 'data' in parent components to child components via url and read the data in child component?

```js
const User = {
  template: '<div><br/>Role read from url is {{ $route.params.role }}</div>'
}

const Home = {
  template: '<div><br/>Welcome</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { name: 'role', path: '/:role', component: User },
    { path: '*', component: Home }
  ]
})


new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
       role: 'default role'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">

  
  The role is (Please change the 'role' value and click on '/User' link): <input v-model="role" type="text" /> <br/>
  
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'role', params: { role: role  }}">User</router-link>
   
 
  <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
  
  <router-view></router-view>
  
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to use `$route.params.role`, what I will do is to set the 'props' in router config options to be true.

> When props is set to true, the route.params will be set as the component props.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   routes: [
      { name: 'role', path: '/:role', component: User, props: true },
      { path: '*', component: Home }
   ]
})
```

And bind to the 'props' inside child components.

```
const User = {
   props: ['role'],
   template: '<div><br/>Role read from url is {{ role }}</div>'
}
```